# The fastest way to delete one item from all django sessions?

Tags: django

We calculate and store "region" item for every Django user on our website in their sessions. Sometimes we need to recalc it, and for that we need first to delete this item from sessions of all users. What is the best/fastest way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at Django's middleware